# DoError Using Ansble with Digital Ocean

Tags: python-2.7, ansible, digital-ocean

I've read the posts, I've seen the ticket about the `dopy` version and I've tried to do my due diligence, but...

> An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: NameError: name 'DoError' is not defined

This is still kicking my arse. I'm running OS X El Capitan. I've installed python + pip via Homebrew and I've tried installing Ansible via both Homebrew and pip. I'm still getting the error. What am I missing?

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
$ which ansible
/usr/local/bin/ansible
$ python --version
Python 2.7.11
$ pip --version
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.0.1.0
  config file = /Users/robwilkerson/Development/uw/ansible-servers/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
$ pip list
...
dopy (0.3.5)
...
```

I've tried everything I can think of. If I use the system python and try to install pip without ansible I get an OpenSSL error that's a known issue.

I could really use a shove in the right direction.

Comment: What tickets about dopy? The question is missing a bunch of context right now

Comment: it wasn't a dopy ticket, but an Ansible ticket: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/2509. What other context can I provide that might help?

Comment: I experienced the same issue, using CraigMason's workaround seemed to do the trick (i.e. setting `localhost ansible_python_interpreter=python` in the hosts file)

Comment: this did the trick for me: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/2509#issuecomment-195864794

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to:

1. use Python 3.x
2. use virtual environment for ansible and python modules, eg. `python3 -m venv ~/.venv && . ~/.venv/bin/activate`
3. `pip install -IU pip && pip install ansible dopy`